# Help Needed With Finding Image Data In DOS Game File

Tags: assembly, c, file-format, hex, dos

I have been analysing, an File called FW190AS.PAC from a 16 Bit Game called Secret Weapons Of The Luftwaffe, in a Hex Editor, the Bytes are displayed in Little Endian format. My aim with this game, is to eventually change The Planes shapes in the game for the outside View, i.e. they are basic Bitmap images, to other shaped Planes. There is another File called FW190A.PAC which also contains images for different views of the Plane and other info. My feeling the 'S' at the end of the name of the File, refers to Shape.

Through trial and error and narrowing down byte sections in the FW190AS.PAC File, I have noticed for example, that when I change byte values, at certain positions at offset 1030 shown in the Hex Editor, one of the views at an angle of the FW190 plane i.e. Focke Wolf 190,

A line attached to the plane, on the right side appears, when I look out the rear view mirror view, changing the bytes produces different coloured sections on the line, each time I change the values. Also when I Change Bytes For Offsets 1000 to 10F0, with Bytes from the Corresponding Offsets in BF109GS.PAC,
gives a certain angle view of the BF109G, not facing forwards but Northeast for the FW190A. When I change bytes in offset 1720 in FW190AS.PAC the Upwards View looks different.

Also If I do the same with the bytes, from offsets 1100 to 1400 in the BF109GS.PAC File, to offsets 1100 to 1400 in the FW190AS.PAC File I get the BF109G shown in the opening movie in the game instead of the FW190A.

I also believe that the different angle Views, for the outside views of the Planes in the game, are at different offsets in the shape Files. I am convinced too, that the Bytes for the different, outside angle views of the Planes, are at different offsets for the different planes' Shape Files, as the BF109GS.PAC bytes for the offsets 1000 to 10F0, give a different view for the BF109G,
to the bytes from 1000 to 10F0 Offsets in FW190AS.PAC, which is a forward-facing view i.e. for the FW190A. This would make sense, as the total number of offsets, is different in each plane's shape file.

I have attached links to Screenshots of the FW190A, and you will notice the different Colours, in sections of the line showing out of the FW190A, in the different Screenshots. Also In the climbing Plane View changes, when changing bytes in offset 1720, changing the first byte to 07, puts a black line on the left wing, near where it is attached to the fuselage, and also a bitmap, of the original view of the FW190A.

the SWOTL Plane Shape Test 19 and SWOTL Plane Shape Test 20 Screenshot Files I link to amongst others correspond to the Files I named FW190AS (19).PAC and FW190AS (20).PAC respectively, those will need to change back to FW190AS.PAC to be used in the game, choose the Scramble from Brandis Mission, in Historical Missions for the FW190A, and look out of the rearview mirror, to see the new view, it sometimes takes a few seconds, to change to that, bytes were changed at offset 1030.

Here is a C Program that extracts the images from Secret Weapons of the Luftwaffe Files, and saves them as a bitmap, some are in colour most output Greyscale images:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>


    #define MAX_W   600
    #define MAX_H   300   
    #define HEADER_SIZE     54
    #define PALETTE_ENTRIES 256
    #define PALETTE_SIZE    (PALETTE_ENTRIES * 4)   // 4 bytes per entry
#define DATA_OFFSET     (HEADER_SIZE + PALETTE_SIZE)    typedef unsigned char Byte; typedef enum Mode { V1, V2 } Mode; // V1 for
older files, V2 for newer    typedef struct Info {
    Byte image[MAX_H][MAX_W];
    int  min_width, max_width;
    int  width, height;
    int  adder;
    int  output_file_index;
    int  n_palette;
    const char *filename; } Info;    Info info = {
    .min_width = INT_MAX,
    .n_palette = -1,
    .filename  = NULL }; Mode ProgramMode = V1;    void reset() {
    memset(info.image, 0, MAX_H * MAX_W);
    info.min_width = INT_MAX;
    info.max_width = 0;
    info.width = 0;
    info.height = 0;
    info.adder = 0; }    void default_palette(Byte *pal) {
    const int shift = (ProgramMode == V1 ? 3 : 2);
    for (int color = 0; color < PALETTE_ENTRIES; color++) {
        *pal++ = color << shift;
        *pal++ = color << shift;
        *pal++ = color << shift;
        *pal++ = 0;
    } }    void fill_palette(Byte *pal, const char *infilename, int n_palette) {
    if (n_palette == -1) {
        default_palette(pal);
        return;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(infilename, "rb");
    int byte, cnt = 0;
    const int shift = (ProgramMode == V1 ?  3 :  2);
    const int size  = (ProgramMode == V1 ? 32 : 64);
    while ((byte = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (byte == 0xFF && ++cnt == n_palette) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                int r = fgetc(f), g = fgetc(f), b = fgetc(f);
                pal[i * 4    ] = b << shift;
                pal[i * 4 + 1] = g << shift;
                pal[i * 4 + 2] = r << shift;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(f); }    void save_bmp() { 
    Byte header[HEADER_SIZE] = {
        0x42, 0x4D,                  //  0: BM signature
          -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,      //  2: filesize
           0,    0,    0,    0,      //  6: reserved
          -2,   -2,   -2,   -2,      // 10: offset to pixel array
        0x28,    0,    0,    0,      // 14: DIB header size
          -3,   -3,   -3,   -3,      // 18: width
          -4,   -4,   -4,   -4,      // 22: height
        0x01,    0,                  // 26: planes
        0x08,    0                   // 28: bits per pixel
    };
  
    int pad = (4 - info.max_width % 4) % 4;
    int file_size = DATA_OFFSET + (info.max_width + pad) * info.height;
    Byte *output = malloc(file_size);
    memcpy(output, header, HEADER_SIZE);
    *(int*)(output +  2) =  file_size;
    *(int*)(output + 10) =  DATA_OFFSET;
    *(int*)(output + 18) =  info.max_width;
    *(int*)(output + 22) = -info.height;
  
    Byte *pal = output + HEADER_SIZE;
    if (info.n_palette == -1)
        default_palette(pal);
    else
        fill_palette(pal, info.filename, info.n_palette);
 
    for (int h = 0, pos = DATA_OFFSET; h < info.height; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < info.max_width; w++)
            output[pos++] = info.image[h][w];
        for (int p = 0; p < pad; p++)
            output[pos++] = 0;
    }
  
    // Output filenames are: filename-outN.bmp where N is 0,1,...
    char outfilename[100];
    strcpy(outfilename, info.filename);
    char *p = strrchr(outfilename, '.');
    if (p) *p = '\0';
    sprintf(outfilename + strlen(outfilename), "-out%d.bmp",
        info.output_file_index);
  
    FILE *f = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
    fwrite(output, 1, file_size, f);
    fclose(f);
  
    free(output); }    void add(int value) {
    if (info.height < MAX_H && info.width < MAX_W)
        info.image[info.height][info.width++] = value; }    void process(FILE *fp) {
    for (int byte, prev = 0xFF; (byte = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; prev = byte) {
        int count, value;
        if (prev == 0xFF)
            printf("Chunk: %d\n", info.output_file_index);
        switch (byte) {
        case 0xFF: // End of image
            if (prev == 0xFE) {
                if (info.min_width != info.max_width)
                    printf("  Error: min (%d) and max (%d) widths do not match\n",
                        info.min_width, info.max_width);
                printf("  Width: %d  Height: %d\n", info.max_width, info.height);
                save_bmp();
            }
            reset();
            ++info.output_file_index;
            break;
        case 0xFE: // End of image line
            if (info.width < info.min_width) info.min_width = info.width;
            if (info.width > info.max_width) info.max_width = info.width;
            ++info.height;
            info.width = 0;
            break;
        case 0xFD: // next two bytes are count-1 and value
            count = fgetc(fp) + 1;
            value = fgetc(fp);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) add(value);
            break;
        case 0xFC: // next two bytes are count-1 and value
            value = fgetc(fp);  // orig. code had +1 here (but why?)
            count = fgetc(fp) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) // draw dithered line
                add(i % 2 == 0 ? value : value + 1);
            break;
        case 0xFB: // Set adder used in default case
            info.adder = fgetc(fp);
            break;
        default:
            if (ProgramMode == V1) {
                value = (byte >> 3) + info.adder; // High 5 bits are value
                count = (byte & 7) + 1;           // Low 3 bits are count-1
            }
            else {
                value = (byte >> 2) + info.adder; // High 6 bits are value
                count = (byte & 3) + 1;           // Low 2 bits are count-1
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) add(value);
        }
    } }    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 5) {
        printf("Usage: %s [-n] [-p N] INPUT_FILE\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  
    while (**++argv == '-') {
        if (strcmp(*argv, "-n") == 0)
            ProgramMode = V2;
        else if (strncmp(*argv, "-p", 2) == 0) {
            if (argv[0][2])
                info.n_palette = atoi(&argv[0][2]);
            else {
                if (*++argv == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Missing parameters\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                info.n_palette = atoi(*argv);
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unknown switch: %s\n", *argv);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
  
    if (!*argv) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No filename\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    info.filename = *argv;
    FILE *fp = fopen(info.filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        perror(info.filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   
    process(fp);
  
    return 0; }
```

Could someone look at the code, and tell me any changes that could be made to the Code i.e. adapt it ?, to extract the bitmap views from the S.PAC Files i.e. the Plane Shape Files, and save them as bitmaps
in the game ? The .PAC Files are from the FE Folder in the game, and the .PNL Files from the CP Folder. the S.PAC Files are from the AC, i.e. Aircraft Folder in the game. and I have linked to some, of the output bitmap images, of .PAC and .PNL Files.

I watched the following Youtube Video, and particularly looked, at the Fonts Section of the video :-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKb_0BfKtsA&t=1644s

I noticed that when I opened the BF109GS.PAC and FW190AS.PAC
Files in HxD Hex Editor there were repeating Bytes at the top few Offsets, i.e. 01 04 0D 31 01 04 0D 31 01 04 0D 31, on the first offset in the FW190AS.PAC File, then some more repeats
in the BF109GS.PAC File, i.e. 01 07 0C 11 01 07 0C 11 01 06 0C 12 01 06 0C 12 01 06 0C 12 01 06 0D 11 01 06 0D, could these repeats be akin, to what the man in the video says they could be, for the Bioforge Game ? And what sections of code i.e. offsets do they correspond to here, are they saying, where the offsets and bytes, for each of the angle views are in the File?

Here is a link to the game, where you can download it from:-

https://www.abandonwaredos.com/abandonware-game.php?abandonware=Secret+Weapons+of+the+Luftwaffe&gid=2627

I run the 16bit DOS Game in the Program DOSBox, either in version 0.74 or 0.74.3 or the later version 0.83, which has alot more options, than the other two.

Here is a link, to the Files I uploaded :-

https://www.dropbox.com/t/eaq3eQBZ3cSzcoSq

The pacswotl and pnlswotl Folders amongst other files, contain the batch Files and compiled C program.

Also here is another dropbox website link, to Files and Folders which might be useful for this post :-

https://www.dropbox.com/t/lquuXmk6JBz1Hpkk

Could a Moderator, sort out the C Code, some of it hasn't displayed correctly in my post.

Any help and info would be much appreciated. If that is okay ?

Comment: that C code looks like a regular .bmp file parser.. you sure it's supposed to extract images from the game's data files?

Comment: Hi Ali, Yes the code does extract RLE Graphics from the Games Files, i.e. the ones I have in the pacswotl and pnlswotl Folders, in the download link I provide in my post. And saves the Graphics as Bitmap Files.

Comment: I have started to look into the provided files and have several questions:
1) I've tried to `run pac files swotl (Works).cmd` with `*.PAC` files.
While it converts some of them into b/w bmp pictures,
it doesn't generate any bmp files with e.g. `FW190A.PAC` and `FW190AS.PAC`.
Am I doing something wrong, or is that what you want to solve?
2) The posted C program looks like a source code of `PAC-MISC.exe`
but has some difference. `PAC-MISC.exe` accepts `-d` option but the
C program does not. Which is the latest one? Can you provide the source
code corresponding to the `PAC-MISC.exe`?

Comment: 3) When you program the code, what did you use for reference?
The linked Youtube video? Sorry for too many questions. BR.

Comment: Hi tshiono, yes it is for the Files in the AC Folder, in the Game i.e. the S files FW190AS.PAC And Corresponding File i.e. FW190A.PAC and for the other Planes. For example BF109G.PAC BF109GS.PAC HE162.PAC HE162S.PAC etc that I wan't solving. The Codes were written by someone else for me, on this forum see this post :- https://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/181449-how-incorporate-input_byte-loop-query-4.html the code for the Compiled C Program is also on the page. I.e. there are two C codes on that page, there are for pages in total for the thread.

Comment: My main aim is to at some stage, is to be able to get new bitmaps, for the Plane Shape Graphics in the Game i.e. new planes. I.e. change the shape of the Planes etc. 4 pages not for.

Comment: The compiled C program .exe File I called PAC-MISC.exe, the batch files use the -d option, I run the batch files, to run the PAC-MISC.exe file.

Comment: The Youtube Video I post in this thread, I think might be relevant, to how the Files I wan't solving, might be structured, i.e. how the graphics are stored in the file in terms of hex values. The Font section of the Video, is the part that I feel is the most relevant.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I have updated this Post, with another link, with Files that may help you with this. i.e. a File with Website Urls, about VGA Game Graphics etc. All the Game screenshots I have, i.e. I reference which offsets I changed bytes in FW190A.PAC, with pictures of what I get. I.e. the looking down view of the FW190A in the Camera Footage. Which shows change in bits of colour on the right wing etc. I hope these help you.

Comment: 2 Folders, one with Screenshots and another with relevant info.

Comment: Another dropbox website link, added to this post.

Comment: The following Website Link, has a list of topics that could help too :-  http://www.brackeen.com/vga/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanations as well as the links to the additional files.
They are very helpful. I first had thought the problem will be solved in
my spare time, but now I've learned this is a reverse engineering task
with limited source of information. I'll keep on working especially on
weekends but it may take a long time to solve, or I might be at a loss
in the worst case. If that is acceptable for you, I'll try. Cheers.

Comment: Thankyou so much tshiono, Take as long as you need, I also will understand if you are unable to, be successful with this. I wish I was able to do it myself. I think with all the info I have provided, you may be successful with this. I very much appreciate, that your willing to take this task on. Best Wishes Eddie Winch )

Comment: Which part of the world are you living in ? I am in England.

Comment: I am going to bed now, as it is after Midnight here. All the best Eddie )

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and understanding. I'll keep on trying. Btw I'm living in Japan. Best wishes and have a good night. Cheers.

Comment: Hi tshiono, Please let me know, if there is any more info you need, when you need it. For example if you need any more screenshots of the FW190A in the game, i.e. for the FW190A.PAC and or the FW190AS.PAC File. And info about what specific bytes, I have changed at a specific offset in a Hex Editor, i.e. the HxD Program I use for the files in question, that produce changes, that result in the change in colour, i.e. for the FW190A.PAC File the screenshots in the Camera Footage in the Game, like I have linked to, show changes in the Right Wing of the FW190A, i.e shape and colours, in bits.

Comment: Yes, more screenshots of FW190A and the info about bytes are exactly what I wanted. Thank you in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Please keep the "chatter" in comments to a minimum and prefer the chat. If this becomes more excessive, we may move this discussion to the chat. Remember that comments are ephemeral and if context is added in them a question could be missing that context in the future when comments get deleted!

Comment: Here is another Dropbox Link for you, I have the Screenshots with corresponding Hex Values changes, for the FW190A.PAC File. And one to compare with the Original File :- https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/sdjs1m4n26ztljsnwljb8/h?rlkey=ogvgxy2fbosnn1mnwm4afzorn&dl=0   Also in the following Folder from the Second Dropbox Link I uploaded, contain Hex Values Changes Info in the Tests Folders, maybe you could use the corresponding FW190A.PAC in the game and check the camera footage for the Brandis Mission in Historical Missions for the FW190A.  Press C then V to see the changes to the FW190A. Ed Winch

Comment: Okay fair enough 0xC0000022L, I will ask tshiono if we could use chat instead. Regards Eddie Winch

Comment: Hi tshiono, can we use chat instead, if that is okay with you ? Sorry forgot to mention the Folder Path in the previous message it's :- FW190A Original Backup\Misc 8 Test corresponding FW190A.PAC File in the Game.

Comment: Thank you so much for uploading the files. It is absolutely okay for me to move to the chat. Cheers.

Comment: Great, it is after 1am here, so I will chat to you, when you contact me next. I will try and get changes, in the Left wing by altering Bytes, and when I achieve this, I will upload the files.

Comment: Hi tshiono, here is the correct new upload link, sorry the other one was an app one by mistake :- https://www.dropbox.com/t/2iVDjogqMBFDvS9I

Comment: Thank you for the update. Cheers.

Comment: Hello, now I'm trying to reproduce your screenshot "SWOTL Plane shape Test 1.png"
by using "FW190A Original Backup/Misc 8 Test/FW190A.PAC".
As I'm not familiar with the game, I'm not sure whether I'm taking the proper steps.
What I've tried: 1) Press `S` for "SWITCHING SIDES", 2) `H` for "HISTORICAL MISSIONS",
3) `2` to choose "FW 190 A", 4) `3` for "Scramble from Brandis", 5) `S` to start the game.
Then I press `S` to switch the views and am waiting for other planes
to be displayed in a modified/corrupt way, but nothing special happens and eventually my plane is bombed out.

Comment: Would you please let me know the correct steps one by one to reproduce your
screenshots? BR.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I will sort this out for you, when I get home tomorrow, early hours here at the moment.

Comment: Hi tshiono, All the steps are correct, but instead of pressing 'S' to switch views, press 'C' to start the Camera, then after a few seconds, press 'V' to go into the recorded footage, and you will see the modified/corrupt Plane View.

Comment: Thank you for the courteous and clear reply. I've successfully reproduced the plane view
according to your guidance. Now I'll go into the trial and error stage, which may take
a while. I'll be back if I find something or encounter a problem. BR.

Comment: Great no problem tshiono. )

Comment: Hi tshiono, Have you made any progress, since your last post ?

Comment: Hi tshiono, I have managed to cause a glitch, in the Left Wing of the FW190A instead of the Right Wing, changing a byte at Offset AA0 Column 02 in HxD Hex Editor from 0C to 66. changing bytes in Offsets AB0 and AC0, makes more glitches in the Left wing. different colours etc. So if you change bytes at offset BB0 aswell, you have glitches therefore in both wings.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I have been more successful today, with changing the shape of the FW190A. I have uploaded the File and Hex Bytes altered info. choose the Brandis mission take off, and look out the rear view mirror, by pressing 2. At different angles, the white line coming out of the FW190A, is maintained. here is the Dropbox Link :- https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/idqi0mldinnsevo9g67bq/h?rlkey=ysx5ddc3ahzjdd58ndqdscxn5&dl=0

Comment: Hi @tshiono Have you made any more progress, since your last post ?

Comment: I'm so sorry for not responding for a long time. I've missed your last several comments
(since Jul. 28) coz they were not noticed to me by unknown reason. Now I've read them.
I've been working on the analysis of the data observing the camera views
by modifying the byte data of FW190A.PAC one by one especially around the address of 0x0bb6.
They produce different views accordingly including what you have provided. I had
expected the byte value and the view will have some relationship, but I cannot find any significant clue so far.
I'll examine your discovery on Aug. 3 anyway. Best regards.

Comment: No problem @tshiono the File modified on the August 3rd is FW190AS.PAC you will see this if you download the Files, from that dates dropbox.com Link. Best Wishes

Comment: @tshiono Here are some Website links, could you look at them ? I think they will help you :- http://www.brackeen.com/vga/basics.html#1 https://atrevida.comprenica.com/atrtut07.html http://www.brackeen.com/vga/bitmaps.html https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+hex+values+for+a+byte+16+bit&oq=how+many+hex+values+for+a+byte+16&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i160.5933900j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 I.e. in the last link it says a single byte is represted by two hex values i.e. check out What is 1 byte in hex, and in one of those links it says 1 byte represents 1 pixel on the screen in VGA i.e. Mode 13h

Comment: @tshiono I also loaded and the Program decompiled the Secret Weapons Of The Luftwaffe Game exe File. i.e. Swotl.exe in a free version of IDA Pro i.e. Version 5 I typed in search for Text A000 i.e. the Address A000:0000 is significant in Mode 13h in VGA.  This then was followed by 6000h Address in the flow chart. When I opened that, it gave me the second picture in the Screenshots. in the dropbox.com link I provide below there are 16 data segments.

Comment: @tshiono In the AC Folder in the Game, there are 13 S.PAC Files i.e. FW190AS.PAC BF109GS.PAC HE162S.PAC the Sprite or Shape Files for the 13 Planes in the Game and there are 3 other Files called VGA.PAC CAMOFLAG.PAC and CAMOEXP.PAC. Which add up to 16, so I think the 16 Data Segments and those 16 Files must be linked somehow ? Here is the dropbox.com link :- https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/8l0reavccw05jk3f2b8be/h?rlkey=yab2o1827mqwqao5tesaschnz&dl=0 Best Regards

Comment: Hi @tshiono Just before in the File FW190AS.PAC In HxD Hex Editor I changed a byte at Offset 1020 3rd column in, i.e. Column 2 the byte value, from 44 to 22, and a little white line, comes out of the right wing of the FW190A. If you look out of the rear view mirror in the Game, choose the Brandis Mission, in Historical Missions for the FW190A, and takeoff to see this effect. If I change that value from 22 then to 23 then to 24 and on etc, the white line becomes longer each time.

Comment: @tshiono I loaded the Swotl.exe File as an MS-DOS Executable in IDA Pro Version 5. That Version supports DOS Executables and is Freeware.

Comment: Thank you for plenty of additional information. It looks you are almost there
regardless of my participation.
I'm very sorry I must tell you that my current work is getting busy and it is difficult
to take a bunch of time including weekends. I'll try to examine new infos one by one
anyway and I'll be back if I find something new. Sorry for the inconvenience
and thank you for your patience. BR.

Comment: No problem @tshiono I very much appreciate all your help. These things can take time I know. You are marvalous, for being so willing, to do this task for me. Best wishes ))

Comment: Hi @tshiono do you have any experience in using IDA Pro ? As I have mentioned before, I opened the Swotl.exe File in IDA Pro Version 5 as a dos executable. But my knowledge of the program is limited. As is my knowledge of assembly. I am pretty sure I have found where the 16 Files from the AC Folder, are opened i.e. assembly with 16 different DS i.e. Data Segments, but I was hoping to work out how the files are used etc.

Comment: No, I haven't. But I'll try if I can find spare time (can't promise). BR.

Comment: Many thanks @tshiono

Comment: Hi @tshiono How are you ? I have been analysing the Swotl.exe File, in IDA Pro Version 5 Free Version. and using Ghidra to make the changes when I test things. As that free Version doesn't support patching i.e. making changes. I have isolated an area of Assembly Intructions, that when Altered, create Glitches in the colours and how the Aircraft are rendered, i.e. changing SHR BX 1 to SHL BX 1 in that area of code.

Comment: @tshiono I.e. shift right to Shift left changes the colour combinations, and changing other things, can make the aircraft look like space craft not intentionally by me. Also the changes are for all Aircraft, i.e. also in the opening sequence when the Game Loads those effects are shown. 
If you find time to analyse the Swotl.exe in IDA Pro and or Ghidra etc,

Comment: @tshiono I could upload some screenshots to dropbox. And tell you which area of Code to look at. I no longer think the 6000h Data Segments are the Plane Shape Data, as changing 6000h to something else in the assembly, the planes still show in the game when I do that. I am hoping to find a specific Data Segment for the FW190A in the Assembly. So I will keep trying.  Eddie Winch )

Comment: @tshiono the Colour changes also effect the Fire Colours i.e. the Fireball when a Plane blows up or a target is destroyed etc.

Comment: What a remarkable progress! I suppose you will be almost there. Good luck for your next discovery. BR.